# ASP.net permissions to root certificate store

Tags: asp.net, permissions, certificate

Is it possible to give asp.net read permission to the certificate store?

If yes , how?

If no... do I need to set the permission manually per certificate file?

If yes where are these files physically on the HDD?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally you give permissions to **A** certificate. I use a method like this to find the custom made cert and grant permissions. If you are using a cert issued by a public entity like Verisign, Thawte, etc, this is probably unnecessary.

```
FindPrivateKey.exe My LocalMachine –n "CN=<certificate issuer>"
```

...will find certificates on the local machine in the personal store for a particular issuer.

*Note: If FindPrivateKey is not on your local machine, 
download the WCF samples, including the FindPrivateKey tool, at 
[http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21459](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=2611A6FF-FD2D-4F5B-A672-C002F1C09CCD&displaylang=en)*

FindPrivateKey returns the location of the private key for the certificate, similar to

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\Machinekeys\4d657b73466481beba7b0e1b5781db81_c225a308-d2ad-4e58-91a8-6e87f354b030".
```

Run the following command line to assign read only access permissions to the process identity of the ASP.NET/WCF Service

```
cacls.exe "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\Machinekeys\4d657b73466481beba7b0e1b5781db81_c225a308-d2ad-4e58-91a8-6e87f354b030" /E /G "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE":R
```

NOTE:  If you are running Microsoft Windows® XP, give the certificate permissions for the ASPNET identity instead of the NT Authority\Network Service identity, because the IIS process runs under the ASPNET account in Windows XP.

Certificates are viewable from the MMC snap in for Certificates. Open MMC, choose File --> Add/Remove Snap in, click the add button and choose certificates. From here you will need to choose the appropriate store (usually Computer Account - Local Computer for ASP.NET items) to manage and then you can view/admin the certs.

Please take a good hard look at the different command line options, and make sure that you have a clear understanding of what certificates are and how they work before granting any permissions.

Comment: Syntax for icacls.exe is:

    icacls.exe file /grant "user":(R)

Comment: To view and set permissions from MMC, Right-click on the certificate you need, from the context menu select All Tasks... -> Manage Private Keys...

Comment: On Windows Server 2008/Windows 7 you should find these certificates in the folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`

Comment: @PeterTate  Is there any way to do this for public-keys?

Answer (score 9):

The network service account that asp.net run under by default doesn't have access to the local machine personal certificates. Grant access by the following:

Repost from [Sohnee @ forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/p/1076979/1584772.aspx)

> Step 1 - if you don't already have it
>   installed - get [WinHttpCertCfg](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C42E27AC-3409-40E9-8667-C748E422833F&displaylang=en)
>
> Step 2 - if you already have the
>   certificate installed on the machine
>   and you just need to grant access to
>   Network Services:
>
> > WinHttpCertCfg.exe -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -s "IssuedToName" -a "NetworkService"

Answer (score -7):

Don't really like answering my own questions, but one simple way to get rid of this error is just to give network service full access to the c:\drive, and propagate permissions down.

You'll shoot me down I know, telling me how bad this is - but it works.

Comment: Agreed, that's a very unsafe practice.

Comment: This solution is suitable only for testing, and only temporarily.