# How to give permission to Network service to install certificate in certificate store

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, certificate, x509certificate, network-service

We have developed a ASP.Net application. My apppool is running under Network Service Identify.Throug code we need to install a certificate. As my app pool is running with Network Service Privilages, it is throwing cryptographic exception "Access Denied".

I've tried the following option:

1. Given Full permissions to Network Service for the following path:
   "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys"
2. installed and the below tool to give permission to network service.
   WinHttpCertCfg.exe
   Not able to give permissions to Certificate Root. This tool is only helpful to give permission to access a specific certificate.

Please help me on resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to article found at msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384088(v=vs.85).aspx

It says:

> Note  The user must have sufficient privileges to use this tool, which requires the user to be an administrator and the same user who installed the client certificate, if installed.

So check if network service is member of local administrators group.

Answer (score 0):

whole story
[ASP.net permissions to root certificate store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271497/asp-net-permissions-to-root-certificate-store)

download WCF sample projects from the link below and compile FindPrivatekey project.  ( tips: Add reference  system.security otherwise you will catch a undefine X509Certificate2UI function error )
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21459